# All versions for has_many relationship using paper_trail

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, has-many

What would be the cleanest and most efficient way to get the versions for both the object and it's children using the `paper_trail` gem?

For example:

```
class Car
  has_paper_trail
  has_many :wheels
end

class Wheel
  has_paper_trail
  belongs_to :car
end
```

To get all the changes made to both `Car` and `Wheels`, I would do something like this:

```
car = Car.find 1

# will return car.versions + car.wheels[0].versions + car.wheels[1].versions, etc.
car.all_versions
```

I have not been able to find any documentation about that in `paper_trail`.

Comment: have you read something about the `paper_mail`?

Comment: @majioa No, and I don't think it's relevant to the question.